# How to create two rows that occupy the full viewport height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and what to create a layout where it occupies the full viewport both horizontally and vertically.

I have two rows. The first at 60% of the height of the viewport and the second 40% of the viewport. So basically with some ASCII art:

```
 ----------------------------
|  60% Of View Port Height   |
|                            | 
 ----------------------------
|  40% Of View Port Height   | 
 ----------------------------
```

I have looked at various posts on Stack Overflow but cannot find a solution that will work across all devices in a responsive fashion. I would prefer a native Bootstrap 3 solution but other solutions also welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way is adding the needed height to the rows

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.viewport {
    height: 100%;
}

.thick {
    height: 60%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #800;
}

.thin {
    height: 40%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #080;
}
```

```html
<div class="container viewport">
    <div class="row thick">
        <div class="col-xs-12">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row thin">
        <div class="col-xs-12">world</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap the rows in a 100/100 container, and use `table-row` to get the desired height...

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="row sixty">
      <div class="col-md-12">60%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row forty">
      <div class="col-md-12">40%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  height:100%;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.row {
  width:100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.row > div {
  width:100%;
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}

.row.forty, .forty>div  {
  height:40%;
}

.center-row.sixty, .sixty>div {
  height:60%;
}
```

Bootply: http://bootply.com/98168